# Helm Chart/Statefulset dinamically set a pods to determined nodes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm, redis-cluster

So this is a little bit related with [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336104/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-specific-node-for-each-statefulset-pods), but I have a determined example that I think justify this use case.

I am installing a redis-cluster using [bitnami/redis-cluster helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/redis-cluster). This works with 6 instances, 3 master + 3 slaves, that are deployed over 3 nodes. My idea then, its that these instances were deployed over 3 nodes, avoiding master 1 and slave 1 (for example) were not in the same node, so if one node fails I have its replica in one of the other nodes.

What I am doing actually, is set a custom scheduler for this nodes, and in the end of deployment execute an script that manually sets each instance in the node I want.

Is there any way to do this simply using nodeSelector, affinity, taints... directly from values file? I would like to stay on this chart, and don't create a yaml for each redis instance.

Comment: inter pod affinity should work https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity

Comment: With that many replicas, my initial inclination would be to do nothing and expect the default scheduler to spread them around the cluster.  That won't give you a hard guarantee that a single-node failure won't take out multiple replicas, but it's easy.  Do you require the data in Redis to be strongly available, or are you using it more as a cache?

Comment: @Adiii, I thought about this, but the rule will affect all the pods. I would like to say instance 1 and 6 to go to node1, 2 and 4 to node 2, 3 and 5 to node3...

Comment: @DavidMaze, it serves a tyk gateway installation, each time something happend give us a lot of problems. Maybe we are doing more things incorrectly, but appendonly files get corrupt very often